# Quirky Network Behavior

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, dns, domain

I have a situation where I have to support several remote sites, and one in particular is giving me fits. Some symptoms are:

1. If I log the user out remotely, I lose connection to the network, even though I run multiple remote tools as services, and should be able to connect even if no user is logged on.
2. If I execute an application that requires admin access, I lose my connection, and cannot regain it unless someone finishes the execution manually. This happens even though the UAC is disabled.
3. The PC is connected to the domain, yet no users can authenticate into the network from this PC. Users can log into the domain from other devices though. The only account that can log in on this device is a local account. However, I can map drives on the domain manually and the network accepts the user's domain credentials. The device can also see any SQL resources on the domain. I have tried to remove the machine from the domain, and reconnect it, but this has not worked.
4. RDP access is enabled, but any attempt to connect will time out, even if the connection originates from the LAN.

I suspected this might be a DNS or domain controller issue, but records are propagating across the WAN properly, and I don't see anything weird in the DNS logs. Also, the Windows Firewall is disabled, and all traffic is controlled at a Cisco 5505 Firewall. The remote network is connected to a central office via site-to-site VPN. All other devices at all other sites are functioning properly.

If anyone has any insight into what the problem here might be, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: This sounds like a case of non-unique IP addresses. So: how many DHCP servers do you have on the LAN? If you have more than one, are you sure their IP ranges are non-overlapping? Do you have static IPs? If so, are you sure their IP address lie outisde the DHCP range? Check all pcs to make sure that their netmask, gateway and DNS servers are correct.

Comment: This particular segment of the network is 192.168.34.0/24, with one DHCP server from 100-199. I am considering making the devices static. Net masks are 255.255.255.0 and DNS points back to the home office at 0.2. We have DNS on the local site as well (34.2) which mirrors 0.2. I have substituted one DNS server for the other, just in case one wasn't configured properly, and I still have the issues.

Comment: Have you run health checks such as `sfc /scannow` and antivirus scans, or tried to quit and re-join the domain?

Comment: We did those things. At the moment, we can quit and re-join the domain, and then when we log in, we are told that the machine is not on the domain, which it is, of course.